# Increase terminal scale/size on Kali Linux running in VMWare

Tags: kali-linux, display, vmware, display-settings, vmware-workstation

I have a high resolution screen and I'm running the downloadable Kali VM from their site. The problem is everything looks super tiny because of my host laptop screen resolution. In the guest Kali OS, I've gone to Settings > Appearance > Settings tab > Window Scaling and changed it to 2x which seems to have helped almost everything *except* the terminal. Its the entire terminal program, including the File | Actions | Edit | View | Help toolbar at the top is all too small. Increasing the font size within terminal, only affects the 'main' part of the terminal, but I'd like for the entire terminal program to be scaled up.

I am running the downloadable Kali VM (the full VM, not the just the ISO file) on VMWare Workstation Pro 15.5
[image: screenshot of small terminal resolution]

Answer (score 2):

welp to find your answer if you have to use the right words, in my case "high dpi" is what I needed. To anyone needing the solution, Kali ships with something called "Kali HiDPI Mode", turn this on and you're set.

[image: HiDPI in Kali]